# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation - Mysql2 Column cannot be null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I run into a problem when creating a record via FactoryBot, the problem only occurs at the `test` environment.

When I run a command at the **development** console:

`FactoryBot.create(:accounting_pbs_reservation, factor: 3.0)` (Column `factor` is defined at the factories too, but I want to pass it explicitly)

Then it's correctly executed and created, but when I run the command at the **test** environment, then it prints the error:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
  Mysql2::Error: Column 'factor' cannot be null: 
INSERT INTO `accounting_pbs_reservations` (`start`, `rl_walltime`, `factor`) 
VALUES (1503468000, 1430000, 3.0)
```

Even when the **factor** column is presented.

The problem also occurs when I want to create an instance of the model in RSpec controller.

Did anybody runs into a same problem? The database schema for `test` and  `development`

The database schema for `factor` is set as

```
| Field  | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          
| factor | double | NO   |     | 1       |
```

FactoryBot definition is pretty dump:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :accounting_pbs_reservation do
    factor { 1.0 }
    start { 1_503_468_000 }
    rl_walltime { 1_430_000 }
  end
end
```

RSpec definition where errors occurs:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AccountingPbsReservationsController, type: :controller do
  let(:valid_accounting_pbs_reservation) { FactoryBot.create(:accounting_pbs_reservation) }
  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryBot.attributes_for(:accounting_pbs_reservation) }

...
    context 'when logged as admin' do
      login_admin
      it "returns a success response" do
        get :show, params: { id: valid_accounting_pbs_reservation.to_param         expect(response).to be_successful
      end
...
```

Comment: maybe the value 3.0 is rejected (maybe only int values??) and then a null remains.. Just guessing here

Comment: @NikosM. The problem still persits, the column is set as Double at the database.

Comment: can you try with another value that is not implicit integer, for example 3.123?

Comment: @NikosM. Nothings changed, the error still occurs. Column 'factor' cannot be null

Comment: i guess the problem is in the test code not in mysql. Maybe the test code somehow rejects the factor value or does not take it into account thus passing a null instead

Comment: @NikosM. I don't think so, because when you creating a record via FactoryBot none of the test suites are triggered.

Comment: Have you verified the test DB is set up properly, e.g., same migrations etc as dev?

Comment: Can you share the rspec file and the accounting_pbs_reservation factory (or just relevant parts if it's sensitive) ? It may be that we're looking in the wrong place...

Comment: @DaveNewton I've recreated the test environment by dump of the development database. But it does not helped.

Comment: @sensadrome I've added the test case

Comment: Can you run ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'INSERT INTO `accounting_pbs_reservations` (`start`, `rl_walltime`, `factor`) 
VALUES (1503468000, 1430000, 3.0)' in both envs and report back what happened?

Comment: Also - any significant diffs between your test and dev envs? Are they connecting to the same MySQL server?

Comment: @Grzegorz - So I solved the problem. The problem was at the database trigger, which sets the value to null if the related table is empty. And the table is empty because in test environment I clear the whole database.

Comment: Oof, nice @JanKrupa

Comment: hah yes @JanKrupa - so often something unrelated to what we think the problem is! Glad you sorted it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was at the Database trigger.

The triggers sets `factor` value as **null** if there is no data in a related table. And the related table is empty because when the test are done, it clears the whole database.